# In wordpress multisite how can I allow users to install their own plugins?

Tags: wordpress

My goal is to make it so users can upload their own plugins and themes, and I would like to add most of the things that are in the normal non-multisite WordPress admin as well. What files control the multisite user dashboard in WordPress?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: **you can't**.

Only the main site has a `/wp-content/` folder, all the sub sites are virtualized and share the `/themes/` and `/plugins/` folder with the main site.

From the Codex, [Create_A_Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) <sup>*my emphasis*</sup> :

> A multisite network is a collection of sites that all **share the same WordPress installation**. They can also **share plugins and themes**. The individual sites in the network are virtual sites in the sense that they do not have their own directories on your server, although they do have separate directories for media uploads within the shared installation, and they do have separate tables in the database.

[...]

> Installing themes and plugins is different: for example, each individual site of a network can activate both, but **install neither**.

To achieve what you want, you'd have to grant [***Super Admin***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Super_Admin) capabilities to your users. Meaning that they'd have ***full access*** to the whole network.

The files that control a Multisite are contained in the folder `/wp-admin/network/`, but [*"some are just wrappers for regular admin files one level up"*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/90069/12615).

For example, inside the file `/wp-admin/plugins.php` we have the following which means roughly "if it's Multisite, you can't install plugins":

```
if ( ( ! is_multisite() || is_network_admin() ) && current_user_can('install_plugins') ) { 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo self_admin_url( 'plugin-install.php' ); ?>" class="add-new-h2"><?php echo esc_html_x('Add New', 'plugin'); ?></a>
<?php }
```

With that said, there are some plugins to help with the management of Multisite plugins, but not for the purposes you want: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=multisite+plugins

Answer (score 0):

you can try

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jamjar-plugin-installer/

It supports multi side and allows users to install plugin in their individual sites.

Answer (score -4):

You Can't. But You Can Install Selected Plugins To Your Site. Rename the plugin meenu and the section to plugin market thing..... and then you  can make all the plugins come in a grid form with a screenshot of every single plugin so that if your user wants any of the plugins he can cick-see-the details-then install it.... that would be very sexy. and its faar more easy too..... you just have to tweak in all of your theme's functions.php so that even if a user changes to another theme he wont lose the market.....